# c++ - Does allocating memory to an empty class casues memory leak?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, empty-class, octomap

The following function appears in the [OctoMap](https://github.com/OctoMap/octomap) code:

`class AbstractOcTreeNode {};`  -> They declare an empty class

`AbstractOcTreeNode** children;`  -> This is declared in the `OcTreeDataNode` class header file

```
template <typename T>
void OcTreeDataNode<T>::allocChildren() {
  children = new AbstractOcTreeNode*[8];
  for (unsigned int i=0; i<8; i++) {
    children[i] = NULL;
  }
}
```

Wouldn't this cause memory leak? Shouldn't it be:

```
template <typename T>
void OcTreeDataNode<T>::allocChildren() {
  children = new AbstractOcTreeNode*[8];
  for (unsigned int i=0; i<8; i++) {
    delete children[i];
    children[i] = NULL;
  }
}
```

What am I missing? Thanks for the help!

Comment: `new AbstractOcTreeNode*[8]` just creates the array of pointers. The pointers contained in that array don't point to any instances of `AbstractOcTreeNode` yet.

Comment: In reality there are 100 lines of code between those curly braces, among them are virtual member functions. It is not an empty class.

Answer (score 0):

You'd want to delete the entire array, not each of the individual array elements

```
template <typename T>
void OcTreeDataNode<T>::allocChildren() {
  children = new AbstractOcTreeNode*[8];
  for (unsigned int i=0; i<8; i++) {
    children[i] = NULL;
  }

  // .... later
  delete[] children ;
}
```

You must always match a `new` with a `delete`, and a `new[]` with a `delete[]`, without mixing them.

For completeness (I'm guessing at the context) since the name of the function is `allocChildren` I assume it is their intention to `new[]` the array and *not* cleanup the memory, yet. Hopefully there would be a matching `deallocChildren` that would `delete[]` this memory later.

Comment: Really?  `children` appears the be a member variable and a function called `allocChildren` that frees the memory on exit seems very misleading.

Comment: @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica That's what I thought too. Added a comment to address this.

Comment: I'd expect the cleanup to happen in `OcTreeDataNode<T>::~OcTreeDataNode<T>()` TBH.

Comment: actually it metnions: The tree class manages this pointer, the array, and the memory for it!

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> AbstractOcTreeNode** children;
> ```

`children` can be seen as an array of pointer values.

> ```
> children = new AbstractOcTreeNode*[8];
> ```

We initialize it with an array of eight pointer values.

> ```
> for (unsigned int i=0; i<8; i++) {
>     children[i] = NULL;
> }
> ```

Each of the eight `children[i]` pointer values is initially an uninitialized `AbstractOcTreeNode*`. We assign the `NULL` value to each of them. Calling `delete` beforehand on these uninitialized pointers would be Undefined Behavior.

There is only one memory allocation (`new[]` is only called once), and its result is kept in `children`. There is no leak as long as `children` is eventually cleaned up (using `delete[]`, presumably in the destructor of `OcTreeDataNode<T>`).

Your confusion is the result of having multiple levels of pointers, at least some of which are owning. I personally also find this code hard to read because of that. In modern C++, you would not perform manual memory management, either for allocating the array of pointers (what about `std::vector` or `std::array`) or for the allocation of each `AbstractOcTreeNode`-dervied instance (which is not shown here). You might find `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<AbstractOcTreenode>> children;` in modern C++ instead.

Comment: "Each children[i] pointer value is initially an uninitialized AbstractOcTreeNode*".
So why do they set children[i] = NULL; for each child. 
Furthermore, so if I want to actually set a new child later on to be a OcTreeDataNode obkect, I should use: children[i] = new OcTreeDataNode; ?

Comment: Also, would this be the right way to go if AbstractOcTreeNode wasn't an empty class? i.e 

children = new AbstractOcTreeNode*[8];  just allocates pointers without allocating space for the class objects?
so I can't use children[i], before I set children[i] = new AbstractOcTreeNode; ?

Comment: @RonD Setting it to `NULL` is preferable to leaving it uninitialized. Dereferencing a `nullptr` is very likely to crash the program immediately, dereferencing a random memory value leads to chaos and pain. Plus, calling `delete` on a `nullptr` is fine and does nothing, whereas calling `delete` on an uninitialized value is UB. And yes, `new OcTreeDataNode` could be one way to obtain a pointer to put in there. What does the documentation say?

Comment: Your second comment is correct. `new AbstractOcTreeNode*[8]` just allocates space to hold eight pointer values.

Answer (score 0):

What is the sense to allocate memory and at once to delete it?

```
template <typename T>
void OcTreeDataNode<T>::allocChildren() {
  children = new AbstractOcTreeNode*[8];
  for (unsigned int i=0; i<8; i++) {
    delete children[i];
    children[i] = NULL;
  }
}
```

The function above does not  make sense.

Pay attention to that an empty class has a non-zero size.

And there is allocated an array of pointers to an empty class. Objects of the class are not allocated in this function.

In this function

```
template <typename T>
void OcTreeDataNode<T>::allocChildren() {
  children = new AbstractOcTreeNode*[8];
  for (unsigned int i=0; i<8; i++) {
    children[i] = NULL;
  }
}
```

the variable `children` defined in a namespace gets the address of the allocated array in the member function.

So some other code is responsible to free the allocated memory.

In general it is a bad idea that a member function of a class uses a global variable.